# ERC721 mint() returns 'invalid address' error

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum

I'm trying to create ERC721 token in private network with JavaScript.

I could create ERC721 token through truffle console but failed through JavaScript.

> truffle(development)> myToken.mint()
>
> { tx:'0xc1dc87a29fbe200ff180df67c01e454818feee433b13331c4ea9268624db077b', 
>   receipt:     { blockHash:
>   '0xf2ad0c70cda0efca3460ec74866ed61e77647493feb5edf2f81ad2a038c69956',
>        blockNumber: 251489,...

The error message is

> 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: invalid address'

My code is like below:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');
var contract = require("truffle-contract");
var contractJson = require("./build/contracts/MyToken.json");
var MyToken = contract(contractJson);
Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync = Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.send;
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(web3Provider));
MyToken.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

MyToken.deployed().then(function(mytoken) {
    mytoken.mint();
}
```

Do I need something before the `minting` ?

Comment: You need to either supply a `from` address (`mytoken.mint({ from: ... })`) or set a default one (`web3.eth.defaultAccount = ...`).

Answer (score 0):

## Updated code

Here is an updated test that works with your code.

```
const NFToken = artifacts.require('NFTokenMock');

contract('NFTokenMock', (accounts) => {
    let nftoken;
    const id1 = 1;
    const id2 = 2;
    const id3 = 3;
    const id4 = 40000;

    beforeEach(async () => {
      nftoken = await NFToken.new();
    });

    it('returns correct balanceOf after mint', async () => {
      await nftoken.mint(accounts[0], id1);
      const count = await nftoken.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
      assert.equal(count.toNumber(), 1);
    });
});
```

## Try it

Setting up Truffle requires piles of boilerplate. Let's try it.

```
mkdir tmp && cd tmp
```

Then put this in your package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721": "^2.0.0-rc1",
    "truffle": "^5.0.2",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
  }
}
```

and run `npm install`. Also we need a special hack to get Truffle using the version of the Solidity compiler we want (0.5.1):

```
(cd node_modules/truffle && npm install solc@0.5.1)
```

Now set up a Truffle project:

```
mkdir contracts
echo > contracts/Migrations.sol <<EOL
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
// Boilerplate required, https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1382
contract Migrations {}
EOL
mkdir Migrations
echo > Migrations/1.js <<EOL
// Boilerplate required, https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1382
module.exports = ($)=>{};
EOL
```

Here is your contract. Save it to contracts/nf-token-mock.sol:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

import "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token.sol";
import "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/ownership/ownable.sol";

/**
 * @dev This is an example contract implementation of NFToken.
 */
contract NFTokenMock is
  NFToken,
  Ownable
{

  /**
   * @dev Mints a new NFT.
   * @param _to The address that will own the minted NFT.
   * @param _tokenId of the NFT to be minted by the msg.sender.
   */
  function mint(
    address _to,
    uint256 _tokenId
  )
    external
    onlyOwner
  {
    super._mint(_to, _tokenId);
  }    
}
```

And save the above test file to test/go.js.

If you are lucky then run: `npx truffle test` and you should see

```
Using network 'test'.

Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...


  Contract: NFTokenMock
    ✓ correctly checks all the supported interfaces (55ms)
    ✓ correctly approves account (156ms)


  2 passing (420ms)
```